# How to improve drawing performance in WinForms?

Tags: c#, performance, winforms, drawing

I understand that Winforms is not designed for heavy graphics usage but I don't know anything other than C# so over the years I've created various programs using C# and Visual Studio that push things to the edge (in my opinion) of what can be done effectively with the limitations of Visual Studio / Winforms.

[Example view of the program in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cgzs.jpg)

This program reads Rock Band formatted files and plays them back like a music player, with the added feature that it makes use of the additional information in the Rock Band file like the charts, album art, and lyrics to complete the experience. Everything works pretty well. The drawing is done on graphics, all of it, no images are loaded and moved around (which I found is slower).

Every instance of graphics is accompanied by the following code I found here:

```
graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighSpeed;
graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighSpeed;
```

Which I was led to believe would help with performance.

All the drawing happens based on a timer which runs at 60Hz (16ms) so 60 times per second it draws everything on screen. This works for everything except the lyrics. I can have the lyrics in static mode or karaoke mode no problem. But if I set them to scroll with the vocal notes (in the image above, the blue notes at the bottom, the lyrics should snap to those notes and scroll along with them) it becomes impossible to read them unless you pause, then it's very legible. I've tried playing with the timer's refresh rate from as little as 1ms to 500ms and the behavior doesn't change. Illegible scrolling lyrics.

This is the relevant code for the scrolling lyrics:

```
private void DrawLyricsScrolling(IEnumerable<Lyric> lyrics, Control label, Color color, Graphics graphics)
{
        if (!openSideWindow.Checked || PlayingSong == null || btnPlayPause.Tag.ToString() == "play" || !doScrollingLyrics) 
            return;

        var time = GetCorrectedTime();
        label.Text = "";

        graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighSpeed;
        graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighSpeed;

        using (var pen = new SolidBrush(MediaPlayer.Visible ? picVisuals.BackColor : LabelBackgroundColor))
        {
            graphics.FillRectangle(pen, label.ClientRectangle);
        }

        foreach (var lyric in lyrics.TakeWhile(lyric => lyric.LyricStart <= time + PlaybackWindow).Where(lyric => !(lyric.LyricStart + (PlaybackWindow * 2) < time)))
        {
            var left = (int)(((lyric.LyricStart - time) / PlaybackWindow) * label.Width);
            TextRenderer.DrawText(graphics,lyric.LyricText,label.Font,new Point(left, 0),color);
        }
}
```

I'm hoping you can point me in the direction of what I may be doing wrong or what I may be missing altogether to improve performance, if it is at all possible, within the confines of Winforms. I have over 6,000 lines of unique code in this program so I'm not looking to change to WPF or another language or environment. Either it can be improved in C# / Winforms or it's staying this way.

Thanks!

EDIT:

https://i.imgur.com/vZrpT5F.png

If I disable all other rendering and just have the scrolling lyrics, they still scroll with lag and are not easy to read. This screenshot was taken with the software's own F12-to-take-a-screenshot feature. It stops the action and it looks perfect. If I take a screenshot with Print Screen, same thing. I can't replicate the blurriness/lag short of recording a video I guess.

I found commentary somewhere that using foreach is a lot slower than using a List. So I changed the code to

```
for (var i = 0; i < lyrics.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (lyrics[i].LyricStart < time) continue;
            if (lyrics[i].LyricStart > time + PlaybackWindow) return;
            var left = (int)(((lyrics[i].LyricStart - time) / PlaybackWindow) * label.Width);
            TextRenderer.DrawText(graphics, lyrics[i].LyricText, label.Font, new Point(left, 0), color);
        }
```

No difference in behavior. Also, someone recommended using a periodic timer but that's on .NET 6+, this program is on 4.8.1 so I have no access to periodic timers. Will continue working on it.

Comment: I cannot say much about your specific implentation but unless you have some hardware accelaration via GPU or SIMD, there aren't many options to improve the performance, especially when drawing with a software renderer like gdiplus. However, the most important keypoint to remind is to draw as less things as possible.

Comment: In the code posted here, you might as well remove both the `.SmoothingMode` and `.CompositingQuality` settings. TextRenderer doesn't use GDI+ anti-alias and there's no composition either -- You have to specify where the Graphics object comes from, what surface you're drawing on, whether it's double-buffered and how -- You could run the timed code that calculates the lyrics' position in a ThredPool Thread, then invalidate the canvas each tick. You probably want to use a [PeriodicTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer) for this...

Comment: ...but your code cannot be tested, so it's hard to suggest what could be changed to improve performance (you probably don't want a LINQ query there, though. What you draw should be *pre-cooked*)

Comment: @jtxkopt is it possible to implement hardware acceleration to this project? I'm all ears. I understand the concept that the less I draw the better the performance, but I HAVE to draw all this (or at least give the user the option, they can select which instruments are displayed). So just reducing what is drawn isn't a solution for me.

Comment: @Jimi Like I said there's some 6,000 lines of code for this program, so I struggled with what to share on here. Obviously I can't share the whole code (and nobody would read it). The graphics comes from a picture box where everything is being drawn. I just realized that it's not double buffered so I will try that. I'll remove the LINQ. I had a time where I was letting the automatic suggestions for LINQ-ing code go crazy.

Comment: A PictureBox is double-buffered by default -- I understand that your whole code cannot be posted here. That's why you should build a small demo that can reproduce the problem related to the drawing of the text. It may happen that, while you build it up, you find out that there's a huge difference when no other stuff is drawn, or no difference at all. The result is meaningful anyway -- The Timer's interval counts, even if you appear to think it doesn't; also the type of Timer

Comment: Are you repaining the whole screen over and over? Or do you use some incremental updates. (like only the stuff that is really changing?

Comment: @TrojanNemo I got you but you can reduce the number of things to be rendered, for example, by removing the offscreen objects from your rendering loop,

Comment: @TrojanNemo If you want HW rendering, you should use a HW-accelerated graphics library like Direct2D.

Comment: @Jeroen van Langen everything is constantly changing because even though the lyrics might not change while on screen, their position is changing. So they need to be redrawn at a different place.

Comment: @TrojanNemo instead of redrawing the whole screen, you could check if instead of repainting the whole screen, just move the pixels using [DrawImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481004/c-sharp-move-bitmap-in-picturebox) or similar.

Answer (score 1):

There are something that we can see here

```
foreach (var lyric in lyrics.TakeWhile(lyric => lyric.LyricStart <= time + PlaybackWindow).Where(lyric => !(lyric.LyricStart + (PlaybackWindow * 2) < time)))
{
    var left = (int)(((lyric.LyricStart - time) / PlaybackWindow) * label.Width);
    TextRenderer.DrawText(graphics,lyric.LyricText,label.Font,new Point(left, 0),color);
}
```

From this code and the image you are showing, what I understand is that you are:

1/ Looping over the lyrics, word by word, taking all the items until the current time window

2/ Then you remove the ones that are too early / should have scrolled into non-view

3/ Then you render those words, one by one

Neither the LinQ nor the word by word rendering was efficient, and it is especially inefficient to do so 60 times a second. My suggestion: Render the whole (or a few minutes worth of) lyric in one go and "slide" the whole rendered text sentence instead

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a try. I have to figure out how to pause and resume with such a method of doing things but i assume it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can try maybe to use EmguCV which is C# .net wrapper for OpenCV (machine vision library written in C++) which has, among other things, built in functions for drawing text/shapes on images.
The libraries from NuGet are: Emgu.CV and Emgu.CV.runtime.windows
If this is relevant to you, drop a comment, and I will add few more pointers on the subject.